# Logistic Regression: How to find top three feature that have highest weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I am working on UCI breast cancer dataset and trying to find the top 3 features that have highest weights. I was able to find the weight of all features using `logmodel.coef_` but how can I get the feature names? Below is my code, output and dataset (which is imported from scikit).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    cancer.data, cancer.target, stratify=cancer.target, random_state=42)

logmodel = LogisticRegression(C=1.0).fit(X_train, y_train)
logmodel.coef_[0]
```

Above code outputs weights array. Using these weights how can I get the associate feature names?

```
Output:
    array([  1.90876683e+00,   9.98788148e-02,  -7.65567571e-02,
             1.30875965e-03,  -1.36948317e-01,  -3.86693503e-01,
            -5.71948682e-01,  -2.83323656e-01,  -2.23813863e-01,
            -3.50526844e-02,   3.04455316e-03,   1.25223693e+00,
             9.49523571e-02,  -9.63789785e-02,  -1.32044174e-02,
            -2.43125981e-02,  -5.86034313e-02,  -3.35199227e-02,
            -4.10795998e-02,   1.53205924e-03,   1.24707244e+00,
            -3.19709151e-01,  -9.61881472e-02,  -2.66335879e-02,
            -2.44041661e-01,  -1.24420873e+00,  -1.58319440e+00,
            -5.78354663e-01,  -6.80060645e-01,  -1.30760323e-01])
```

Thanks. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
coefs=logmodel.coef_[0]
top_three = np.argpartition(coefs, -3)[-3:]
print(cancer.feature_names[top_three])
```

This prints

```
['worst radius' 'texture error' 'mean radius']
```

Note that these features are the top three, but they are not necessarily sorted among themselves. If you want them to be sorted, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
coefs=logmodel.coef_[0]
top_three = np.argpartition(coefs, -3)[-3:]
top_three_sorted=top_three[np.argsort(coefs[top_three])]
print(cancer.feature_names[top_three_sorted])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me what `np.argpartition(coefs, -3)` does?

Comment: The function np.argpartition(coefs, k) will return an array that starts with the indices of the smallest n-k elements in coefs and ends with the indices of the largest k elements in coefs. Since it does not perform a full sort, it is more efficient than doing a full sort of the array (note that using -3 in the function is the same as using len(coefs)-3). If you don't need the efficiency you could also replace that row with top_three = np.argsort(coefs)[-3:]

Comment: I was wondering if I need to do sorting at all? `top_three = np.argpartition(coefs, -3)[-3:]` gives me the top three most weighted features, right? but why do I need to sort `top_three_sorted=top_three[np.argsort(coefs[top_three])]`. Will that not change the result?

Comment: Based on your question you don't need the extra sotring, and top_three = np.argpartition(coefs, -3)[-3:] will do the job. I just wasn't sure when I read it originally (I wasn't sure if you just need the top three, or if you want to have them ordered like [third largest, socond largest, largest]), so I answered on both scenarios

Comment: Thank you for helping on this

Comment: Note that this will print them in ascending order (least important to most important), which is not so intuitive, at least to me. So I simply reversed the list `top_three_sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=len(data.columns)-1

percentage_change=[]

for i in range (n):

    cp=(difference[i]/wei[i])*100

    percentage_change.append(cp)
    
columns=list(data.columns.values)

indices=sorted(range(len(percentage_change)), key=lambda i: percentage_change[i])[-3:]

print("the top 3 features which have higher % change in weights ")

for j in indices:

    print(columns[j])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].